# Selenium Find By X path Errror

Tags: python, selenium, web, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am new to Selenium and am trying to scrape YouTube but I encountered a weird problem. I was trying to scrape the following HTML:

[image]

This is my code:

```
a = w.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='yt-simple-endpoint style-scope ytd-video-renderer']")
```

When I do this in the interactive shell then it works fine but when I rerun the script after saving it then it shows me an error saying the element can't be found.

Comment: Please insert the code as text instead of the pictures.

Comment: This seem to be timing issue. You can try to implement [Implicit or Explicit wait](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

Comment: Maybe the a element is into a frame. You should change to the frame, before try find the element.

Comment: Or maybe there are more than one element with this xpath. Try use findelements function and after that print the size of the list.

Comment: I don't get one thing. It works in interactive shell but not when I rerun the script. Moreover the same problem occurs when I try to scrape Instagram.

Comment: Is there some reason you aren't using the ID?

Comment: You can go like this as well `find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='video-title']")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems this is a purely a synchronization issue. We need to induce `WebDriverWait` i.e `ExplicitWait` to sync up the driver instance with the browser instance as follows:

```
a = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda x: x.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='yt-simple-endpoint style-scope ytd-video-renderer' and contains(@title,'Calvin Harris - Summer')]"))
```